# Compute the sum of an exponent divided by factorial

Tags: summation

There was much discussion on Math SO why

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}  = 0$$

when $\alpha > 1$. What would be the strategy for computing:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}$$

given that it's convergence is easlity proven using *ratio test*.

Comment: This is sometimes taken to be the *definition* of $\exp \alpha$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}$? What is $x$?

Comment: @JohnDoe Fixed it. Sure it's $n$.

Comment: @carmichael561:  after the edit the sum is $e^\alpha$  The lower limit of the sum was updated, so you were right at the time.

Comment: What do you mean by "the strategy for computing ... ?"  The series is one characterization of the exponential function $e^\alpha$.  Are you asking how to obtain numerical approximations to the series representation?  Or are you asking whether the series has a closed-form?

Answer (score 3):

The summatory you are proposing is the represantion of $e^{\alpha}$. This is obtained using Taylor Series
: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

$$e^\alpha = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{\alpha^n}{n!} $$

As your summatory start with $n=1$ then it would be: $$e^{\alpha }-1 = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{n!}$$, since:

$$ e^\alpha = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{\alpha^n}{n!}=\frac{\alpha^{0}}{0!} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{n!} = 1 +\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{n!}  $$

Comment: As your summatory start with $n=1$ then it would be: $e^{\alpha }-1 = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{n!}$, since $ e^\alpha = \frac{\alpha^{0}}{0!} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{n!} = 1 +\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{n!}  $

Answer (score 1):

The power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges for all $x$.  If we call it by $f(x)$, notice that
$$
    f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}
          = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
          = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{m}}{m!} = f(x)
$$
Also, $f(0) = 1$.  These two properties characterize the exponential function, by uniqueness of solutions to ordinary differential equations.  Therefore $f(x) = e^x$ for all $x$.

Comment: There are several characterizations of the exponential function.  The power series representation is one.  Others include the limit definition, the inverse of $\int_1^x \frac1t\,dt$, and the Lebesgue measureable function that satisfies the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, with $f(1)=e$.  The ODE that you discuss is another one yet.  The point is that we have the series to begin and can take that as The Characterization.  And we are done.

Comment: @Dr.MV I agree with everything you said except the sentence "The point is..." If the student is trying to show that the series converges to $e^\alpha$ and answers “by definition”, and is working within a framework where that is *not* the definition of the exponential function, then that answer doesn't help.

Comment: @Dr.MV: When I was taking my quals a satirical version was distributed at the same time with the question: "Define for a topological space $X$ and natural number $n$ the $n$th homotopy group $\pi_n(X)$.  Compute $\pi_{14}(S^{10})$."  A clever person responded that the best way to answer the question was to define $\pi_n(X)$ to be zero.  Then $\pi_{14}(S^{10})$ is easy to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

As supplemental to the other answers, and as I feel like that real powers should be defined before we get into Taylor series or differential equations, here is a direct approach using just the binomial theorem.

The usual definition of $e$ is $e=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. Through this we can see that $$e^x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{xn}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$$

So this is how we define $e^x$.

Using the binomial theorem, we may write $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n(n-1)..(n-k+1)}{n^k}\frac{x^k}{k!}\leq\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

as $(n-j)/n\leq 1$. Hence $$e^x\leq
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

On the other hand, assuming that $x\geq 0$ we have for $n\geq m\geq 2$

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{n(n-1)..(n-k+1)}{n^k}\frac{x^k}{k!}\leq\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n(n-1)..(n-k+1)}{n^k}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Actually, we do not really have to assume positivity of $x$, just that $m$ is large enough and that $n,m$ are even, and then we can estimate the difference of the RHS and the LHS to be positive, and everything will still work for negative $x$ too.

Taking limits for $n\rightarrow\infty$ this gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{x^k}{k!}\leq e^x$$ for any $m>2$, hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\leq e^x$$

Thus, we have proved that indeed the power series above is equal to $e^x$ 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x$$